# An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker when calling a method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm trying to create a method to change a given field of a given object. I think the my code is fine except when i separated the code only into a method in a different file i got this error.
my controller action looks like this:

```
public ActionResult AddSchedule(Schedule schedule){
    //some code  
    db.Schedules.Add(schedule);
    db.SaveChanges();

    db.Entry(schedule).State = EntityState.Detached;
    Request request = db.Requests.SingleOrDefault(x => x.RequestId == schedule.RequestId);
    TransportDbQuery.SetStatus(request, "RequestStatus", RequestStatus.Approved);
    //some code
}
```

Set Status method

```
public static void SetStatus(object obj, string statusPropertyName, object value){
            using (TransportDbContext db = new TransportDbContext())
            {
                obj.GetType().GetProperty(statusPropertyName).SetValue(obj, value);
                db.Entry(obj).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
```

error is triggered on `db.Entry(obj).State = EntityState.Modified;` line.
As you can see i tried detaching previous object but it still generates the error. Any idea how to fix this?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Are you wrapping your db call in `public ActionResult AddSchedule(Schedule schedule)` in a using statement? If not it won't be disposed thus giving you the mulitple instances error.

Comment: You don't detach the `request` object of which you try to set the status.

Comment: Gert, i thought i might have to attached it. I'm not using request object for anything before changing status. Still i have to detach it? why?

Comment: thanks i added `db.Entry(request).State = EntityState.Detached;` and it worked. But i think its a weak point of EF.